# increasing yRange from negetive to positive in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want my yrange to be between -100 and 0, and here is my plot in gnuplot

I want the y axis to be from -100 increasing up to 0!
what should I do?!
BTW: 
My plot is histogram!
when I set it to [-100:0] my plot is upside down, the bars are from up to down!!

```
set style data histogram
set yrange [-100:0]

set style fill solid 0.3
set bars front
plot 'mean.rssi' using 2:xticlabels(1) title columnheader
```

above is my code, histogram is plotted from 0 to -100, but I want to be from -100 to 0!

The file `mean.rssi` contains two columns, for example

```
Dlink -93
```

Comment: Ok, I think we are getting a bit closer... With this value of -93 you currently get a box from 0 to -93. Do you want to get a box from -100 to -93?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't directly supported, histograms always have their base line at 0, positive values give boxes oriented upwards, negative values downwards.

Since your range is known, you should convert the range [-100:0] to the range [0:100] and relabel the y-axis:

```
set style data histogram
set yrange [0:100]

set ytics ('-100' 0)
set for [i=-100:0:20] ytics add (sprintf('%d', i) i + 100)

plot 'mean.rssi' using ($2 + 100):xticlabels(1)
```

Other solutions would use the `boxes` plotting style. If you could use this depends on whether you need the stacking features of the histogram style.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify ranges with square brackes. For example, to specify both X and Y ranges you could do:

```
plot [-20:20][-50:50] sin(x)
```

which would set the X-range to [-20,20] and the Y-range to [-50,50].

To only set the Y-range, you can set the X-range to the empty brackets `[]`, e.g.

```
plot [][-50:50] sin(x)
```

To only set the X-range you can do something similar, or just omit the Y-range completely:

```
plot [-20:20] sin(x)
```

Comment: when I set it to [-100:0] my plot is upside down, the bars are from up to down!!

Comment: @sgh: But what do you expect? First, check that your axis really goes from -100 to 0 and not from 0 to -100 by accident (it's possible to do that by`set yrange[0:-100]`). Second, histograms are always plottet as boxes or similar ranging from y=0 to the actual value. So, right now, it looks as if gnuplot exactly does what is expected.

Comment: you mean we can't change the central coordinate from [0,0] to [-100,0] in histogram?!

Comment: @sgh Please give a minimal but full example of what you are trying to do!